# "Unwound" a corr.test p matrix, want to remove the p-adjusted duplicates

Tags: r

Corr.test gives a matrix of ps where the lower diagonal are the normal ps and the upper diagonal is the adjusted ps.

What it comes down to is I have a large data.frame where there are duplicates of all correlations and I want to make sure I remove the duplicates that are the p-adjusted section of the matrix.

Say we have a data.frame with just two variables, that came from the unwinding of a correlation matrix of five variables. Unwinding the matrix would give us

```
data <- data.frame(corrnum<-1:25, 
                   pvalue<-rbind(1,.05,.05,.05,.05,.90,1,.05,
                                 .05,.05,.90,.90,1,.05,.05,.90,
                                 .90,.90,1,.05,.90,.90,.90,.90,1)
 )
names(data)<-c("corrnum","pvalue")
```

Where the 1's are correlations with itself that we want to remove. .05s are normal correlations we want to keep. .90s are p-adjusted correlations we want to remove.

I thought this would work:

```
remove<-function(data){
  #How many variables are there? That becomes i.
  i=sqrt(length(data[,1]))

  #Now take the first set to start the shorter data.
  dat<-data[2:i,]

  #Stopnum is where we stopped each previous iterative pull. 
  #Always the product of the number of variables correlated and which variable currently pulling
  #Used for knowing where to start the next pull
  stopnum<-i #*1 technically, but whatever.

    #for each remaining variable
    for (j in 2:i){

    #create a temp dataset
    tempdat<-data[(stopnum+j+1):(j*i),]
    #and create a new stop num
    stopnum<-(j*i)
    #and add the temp to the other dataset
    dat<-rbind(dat,tempdat)
    #and return that to use for the next iteration
    return(dat)
 }
 #and then return it for good.
 return(dat)
 }

 datashort<-remove(data)
```

but it only does one iteration and stops:

```
> data
   corrnum pvalue
2        2   0.05
3        3   0.05
4        4   0.05
5        5   0.05
8        8   0.05
9        9   0.05
10      10   0.05
```

Whereas it should give me:

```
> data
   corrnum pvalue
2        2   0.05
3        3   0.05
4        4   0.05
5        5   0.05
8        8   0.05
9        9   0.05
10      10   0.05
14      14   0.05
15      15   0.05
20      15   0.05
```

Comment: I may not understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to remove the upper triangle and diagonal of a correlation matrix you could do some work within that matrix pre "unwinding" to make this easier.  I've done somewhat similar things in the past by assigning all the unwanted values to `NA` or `0` or something within the matrix.  So if you had a correlation matrix `corrs`, it would be: `corrs[upper.tri(corrs, diag = TRUE)] = NA`.

Comment: I hadn't originally done anything to the original matrix because my only idea was to remove the upper triangle+diagonal, and I needed all of it for some stuff before getting to where I'm at now. I hadn't thought to simply "mark" the upper and diagonal for later removal. Thanks!